# Set Unicode filename in Flask response header

Tags: python, flask, http-headers

I am trying to set the `Content-Disposition` header to send a file to the client. The file name is Unicode. When I try to set the header, it fails with a `UnicodeEncodeError`. I tried various combinations of `encode` and `decode` but couldn't get it to work. How can I send a file with a Unicode filename?

```
destination_file = 'ｐｙｔｈｏｎ_report.html'
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + destination_file
```

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 495, in send_header
    ("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value)).encode('latin-1', 'strict'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 41-42: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RFC 2231 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231#section-4) describes how to specify an encoding to use instead of ASCII for a header value. Use the header option `filename*=UTF-8''...`, where `...` is the url-encoded name. You can also include the `filename` option to provide an ASCII fallback.

Flask >= 1.0 supports calling [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.send_from_directory) and [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.send_file) with Unicode filenames. You can use `send_from_directory` with `as_attachment=True` and a Unicode filename.

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route("/send-python-report")
def send_python_report():
    return send_from_directory("reports", "ｐｙｔｈｏｎ_report.html", as_attachment=True)
```

For security, ensure that you use `send_from_directory` and not `send_file`, if the filename is provided by user input.

---

Prior to Flask 1.0, you can construct the header manually using [the same process Flask uses](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/e630c62987631e45d8d8825212916d14c582c656/src/werkzeug/utils.py#L464-L476).

```
import unicodedata
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/send-python-report')
def send_python_report():
    filename = "ｐｙｔｈｏｎ_report.html"
    rv = send_from_directory("reports", filename)

    try:
        filename.encode("ascii")
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        simple = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", filename)
        simple = simple.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("ascii")
        # safe = RFC 5987 attr-char
        quoted = quote(filename, safe="!#$&+-.^_`|~")
        names = {"filename": simple, "filename*": f"UTF-8''{quoted}"}
    else:
        names = {"filename": filename}

    rv.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", **names)
    return rv
```

---

Until relatively recently (before 2017), browsers did not consistently support this. [This page](https://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attfnboth) has some metrics on browser support. Notably, IE8 will ignore the UTF-8 option, and will fail completely if the UTF-8 option comes before the ASCII option.